# I want to upgrade FLYWAY from community version to Pro version, step by step?

Tags: flyway

I want to update my existing FLYWAY setup from community edition to Pro, need step by step process, where do I need to update Pro license in .conf file and also where do I need to update the edition details if it has to be done in .conf file too, is there any other change which needs to be done to use the undo functionality of FLYWAY Pro edition.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an upgrade guide on the Flyway website, which you can see here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/upgradingToTeams

Excerpt below:

> If you are currently using Flyway Community there are a few things you need to do to upgrade to using Flyway Teams. The process to do so differs depending on how you are accessing Flyway, but broadly consists of telling Flyway to use the [correct edition](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/edition), and supplying a [license key](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/licenseKey). See below for more details for each usage.

Comment: Is there any impact on the existing  FLYWAY setup of community edition? Also I have PRO license  I can still update to PRO instead of Teams?

Comment: Flyway Pro was replaced with Flyway teams in version 7.0.0. Read more about that here: https://flywaydb.org/download/faq#what-happened-to-flyway-pro-and-enterprise-edition

Everything you can do in Flyway community you can also do in Flyway Teams, upgrading your installation as per the guide above simply unlocks new features that would have previously been restricted.

Comment: I have got the license key but while I am adding the key in the config file as invalid key "ERROR: Invalid license key. Ensure flyway.licenseKey is set to a valid Flyway license key ("FL01" followed by 512 hex chars)"

Comment: the license key I am using is as  123-456-789012-AA34   (using imaginary numbers not the actual key for reference)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that looks like a Redgate license key, not a Flyway one. Could you contact sales@flywaydb.org to get instructions on how to find the correct key?

Comment: 1) Successfully Downloaded FLYWAY edition to - Flyway Teams Edition (20 schemas) 7.9.1 by Redgate
2) Updated the New License key in .conf 
3) Added -teams flag in migrate command -> flyway -teams -user=${dbuser} -password=${dbpsw} -url=${jdbcurl} -schemas=${schema} -baselineOnMigrate=true -locations=filesystem:"path to sql" migrate 
4) Updated .bashrc file with export PATH=$PATH:/opt/flyway/flyway-7.9.1 for user "flywayuser".
(Flyway is now running successfully.)